# OCR Exception:Iron OCR InstallationPath Permission Error 1772

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use Iron OCR's library for OCR, I came across this error while trying to do the basics.

```cs
AutoOcr OCR = new AutoOcr() { ReadBarCodes = false };
Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
var Results = OCR.Read(@"Screenshot.png");
Console.WriteLine(Results.Text);
```

OCR Exception:Iron OCR InstallationPath Permission Error 1772.   Could not deploy and run IronOCR resources to path '' for user 'MYPCNAME\MYUSER'.  This can be fixed globally by setting IronOcrInstallation.InstallationPath to a directory on disk with file read and write permissions.  Please refer to documentation at http://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/docs/html/P_IronOcr_IronOcrInstallation_InstallationPath.htm

This is the full error I get every time I try to run this code. If anyone could give me a hand, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: What is it that you don't understand about `This can be fixed globally by setting IronOcrInstallation.InstallationPath to a directory on disk with file read and write permissions`?

Comment: How does someone do exactly that?

Comment: This is what I did to add the installation path, its a static property in the IronOcr namespace in the IronOcrInstallation class.

            IronOcr.IronOcrInstallation.InstallationPath = @"C:\Local\TEMP\OCR\";
            var ocr_processor = new IronOcr.AutoOcr();

However, that still didnt fix my issue, so I'm looking for something else.  I'm running on Windows Server 2016, but the same code runs on Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

That permission message is pretty misleading and wrong for most of the cases, I solved it by installing the c++ runtime (32+64) and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was due to using .net core. IronOcr does not support it, use .net framework instead. Unfortunately they didn't bother to document this clearly.

Thanks staind852 for the suggestion on [github](https://github.com/iron-software/Iron-OCR-Image-to-Text-in-CSharp/issues/5#issuecomment-588534603)

Comment: IronOcr now fully supports Standard, Core  and .NET 5 in 2021 .